# DJango REST Framework: How to write Create, List, Update and Delete with ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm still new to python/django and currently I'm trying to add REST API using django rest framework. This is currently what I have:

urls.py

```py
actions_url = {'actions': {'get': 'list', 'post': 'create'}}
actions_obj = {'actions': {'get': 'retrieve', 'delete': 'destroy', 'put': 'update'}}

urlpatterns = [
   path('book', BookViewSet.as_view(**actions_url)),
   path('book/<str:isbn>', BookViewSet.as_view(**actions_obj))
]
```

models.py (The model doesn't have PK)

```py
class Book(models.Model):
   BNAME = models.CharField(
       db_column='BNAME',
       max_length=30,
       default='')

   BISBN = models.CharField(
       db_column='BISBN',
       max_length=10,
       default='')
```

views.py

```py
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   name = serializers.CharField(source="BNAME")
   isbn = serializers.CharField(source="BISBN")

       class Meta:
           model = models.Book
           fields = ('name', 'isbn')


class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet)
   queryset = Book.objects.all()
   serializer_class = BookSerializer

   def list(self, request):
       return queryset

   def create(self, request):
       pass

   def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       pass

   def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       pass

   def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       pass
```

So now my questions are:

1. If I'm not including `def create(self, request)` in the `BookViewSet` for example, I assume when I make a `POST /book` it will do nothing?
2. I'm struggling to understand what to put inside `create`, `retrieve`, `update`, `destroy`. For example if I make a `PUT /book/123` with params: `{ isbn: '123', name: 'test'}`, what do I need to do in `def update` to retrieve those data from request then update data to database?
3. I want to validate `isbn` and make sure it is unique/no duplicate before saving a record/update it to database, what should I do? I tried reading about Validator: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/ and looks like I need to update serializer:

```py
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source="BNAME")
    isbn = serializers.CharField(source="BISBN", validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Book.objects.all())>])

        class Meta:
            model = models.Book
            fields = ('name', 'isbn')
```

Is this correct?

4. Similar to previous question, but now I want to make sure both `isbn` and `name` are unique together, I assume this is what I need to do:

```py
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source="BNAME")
    isbn = serializers.CharField(source="BISBN")

        class Meta:
            model = models.Book
            fields = ('name', 'isbn')

        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Book.objects.all(),
                fields=('name', 'isbn')
            )
        ]
```

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you writing your own `ViewSet` actions?  Might want to start with the default actions as suggested in [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example), then modify if you really need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your implementation of `create(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` will do nothing because the function is empty, it won't even return a response.
2. You don't have to put anything in `create`, `list`, `retrieve`, `update`, `partial_update`, and `destroy` because you're using the `ModelViewSet` class.  The `ModelViewSet` provides a default implementation for all of them.  If you really want to keep your overrides though you could use this implementation instead:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """You could add some documentation here"""
    return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

We're using `super()` because it is calling the parent implementation of `create`.

3. What you're doing is correct, let me just add that I would personally put a `unique=True` on the model field rather than adding the validator to the serializer.  Rest Framework is smart enough that the serializer will inspect the model field and add the unique validation auto-magically.  If you'd rather avoid the unique index on your database then your use of `UniqueValidator` is correct I think.

`BISBN = models.CharField(db_column='BISBN', max_length=10, default=None, unique=True)`

Keep in mind that you may be susceptible to race conditions without the unique index on the database.  By this I mean that two books could be created/updated to have the same isbn if these operations occur at the same time.

4. Again, I would apply validation for multiple fields on the model using the `Meta.unique_together` attribute of the model, i.e.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    # fields...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("BNAME", "BISBN")
```

However if you don't want a unique index on your database for this then your use of the `UniqueTogetherValidator` is correct.

I have another tidbit I think is worth mentioning:

You view should have a `lookup_url_kwarg` and `lookup_field` to work with the isbn in your url definitions.

```
class BookViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    lookup_url_kwarg = "isbn"  # Use the 'isbn' from your url definition
    lookup_field = "BISBN"  # Use the `BISBN` field on your database/model to perform the lookups
    # ...
```

If you want to handle multiple url kwargs, then you will need to customize the `get_queryset()` method.  In the following code I use `isbn` to filter the queryset, and then let the view lookup the book by name.

```
class BookViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    lookup_url_kwarg = "name"
    lookup_field = "BNAME"
    def get_queryset(self):
        # self.kwargs is a dictionary containing your url kwargs.
        isbn = self.kwargs.get("isbn")
        book_queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return book_queryset.filter(BISBN=isbn)
```

Comment: Thank you. How would `lookup_url_kwarg` and `lookup_field` work if my url is `book/<str:isbn>/<str:name>`?

Comment: I've added another sample to the bottom of my answer, you essentially need to customise the `get_queryset` method to filter by isbn (and anything else you want for that matter).  I've found I do a lot of customization to the `get_queryset()` when the API isn't strictly flat.